# How to specifically delete a dynamically added element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I know the question is not so understandable and might also be duplicate but i cant find the specific solution of my problem so allow me to elaborate.

I am displaying lots of images using bootstrap in article thumbnails 
I am using PHP to get the values from the database
I am using a foreach loop and adding elements dynamically
here's a snippet:

```html
foreach ($cursor as $document) 
{
  foreach ($document["Pics"] as $photos) 
  {
    echo "<article id='hasMenu' class='development design'>
      <a href=".$photos["Photo"])." class='swipebox'>
        <img  src=".$photos["Photo"]." class='work img-responsive'>
      </a>
    </article>";
  }
}
```

This code fetches all the images from the database and displays it on my page

Now this was the adding part i am having problem in deleting the specific image. I am using a right click context menu but i am not able to get a specific element which i want to delete as there is no id or class name because i dont know how much images will be added....

Here's my context menu snippet:

```
$(function() {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: "#hasMenu",
    callback: function(key, options) {
      if (key == "delete") {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
      }

      if (key == "open") {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
      }
    },
    items: {
      "open": {
        name: "Open", 
        icon: "edit"
      },
      "delete": {
        name: "Delete", 
        icon: "delete"
      },
    }
  });

  $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked ', e);
  })
});
```

By this I add a right click context menu that shows Delete and open option.

Now when i will click on delete i want to get the ID of that specific image(article) which i want to delete...

I hope my problem statement is clear...

Comment: Which context menu plugin are you using? Generally speaking the event provided to the callback should tell you which element the context menu was raised on

Comment: https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu this one....

Comment: Thanks. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your PHP loop is generating a lot of HTML elements all with the same `id` of `hasMenu`, which is invalid. You should change that to a class.

You can then attach the context menu plugin to the elements with that class. Finally you can use the `this` keyword within each callback function placed on the buttons to reference the elements which triggered the menu to be shown in the first place. Try this:

```js
$.contextMenu({
  selector: ".hasMenu",
  items: {
    "open": {
      name: "Open",
      icon: "edit",
      callback: function(key, opt) {
        $(this).find('span').show();
      }
    },
    "delete": {
      name: "Delete",
      icon: "delete",
      callback: function(key, opt) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.hasMenu span { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.4.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.4.5/jquery.contextMenu.min.css" />

<div class="hasMenu">Right click me... #1 <span>Opened content...</span></div>
<div class="hasMenu">Right click me... #2 <span>Opened content...</span></div>
<div class="hasMenu">Right click me... #3 <span>Opened content...</span></div>
<div class="hasMenu">Right click me... #4 <span>Opened content...</span></div>
<div class="hasMenu">Right click me... #5 <span>Opened content...</span></div>
```

Comment: Wow man its working perfectly now.... thank you soo much i spent whole day on this... :P

Comment: Rory McCrossan Sir i am facing an another problem regrading something similar

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".comments").click(function(){
  
 on every $(this) i want to
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});

can you please tell me how to do this???

Comment: i just cant upvote the answer my rank is too low for... but i have clicked on the right mark...